# Opensocial v9 : Is there a way of requesting only certain field from orkut

Tags: request, paging, opensocial

I am trying to write a pager from my application which require to get the total number of albums. I can fetch all albums from the orkut but it slow down the transfer rate since I only need the total not the data in the albums.

Does opensocial v9 has a function I can check how many albums a viewer has? or maybe I fetch only the ID of the albums so I can minimize the transfer time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opensocial suports pagination by providing developers the ability to add `startIndex` and `count` parameters to DataRequests ( and other *Requests). If developer does not supply a `count` parameters, its detault is `20`, and as you guess, when a `startIndex` parameter isnt supplied, it defautls to `0(zero)`.

Response you get must be something like:

```
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "totalResults": 120,
  "entry": [
    ....
  ]
}
```

Here, `totalResults` is the total number of albums, not the returned album count.
You can use `totalResults` to calculate your page count and prepare your pagination.

**Update:**
opensocial.DataRequest.MediaItemsField.MAX field probably used while making MediaItemRequests, however to make a album list AlbumRequest should be used.
you can limit the number of albums fetched in this pipeline

```
<os:AlbumsRequest key='myalbums' userid="@viewer" groupid="@self" />
```

by adding a `count` parameter, such as:

```
<os:AlbumsRequest key='myalbums' userid="@viewer" groupid="@self" count="5"/>
```

this album request fetches at max 5 albums of viewer.
the resulting json would be:

```
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "totalResults": ....here total number of albums....,
  "entry": [
    ....here at max 5 albums....
  ]
}
```

Here you can get total number of album by calling `myalbums.totalResults`.

Comment: Do you mean the parameter opensocial.DataRequest.MediaItemsField.MAX = something values.... and use the response collections.getTotalSize.

Comment: Oh sorry, I need for albums as well as photos. I used the DataRequest.send and get the response object but I couldn't find the totalResults instead I have a Collection object for albums that contain a function 'getTotalSize()'. I assume the 'getTotalSize' is the function I really wanted but it wasn't. It gave me 5 fetched albums.